# python remove edges in stacked area chart

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am trying to remove the "edge color" from a stacked area chart in python, as the plots tend to get "overlaid" by the "last" column:

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 10000, size=(10000, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt, seaborn as sns
def myplot(df):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(4, 4))
    df.plot.area(ax=ax)


myplot(df=df)
```

The problem is that it looks as if the red variable is the "largest one". But that is a plotting artifact because its borders from one x value t othe next overlap  that of other variables. To see what I mean, run this (same data with only 100 observations)

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 100, size=(100, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt, seaborn as sns
def myplot(df):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(4, 4))
    df.plot.area(ax=ax)


myplot(df=df)
```

Comment: Did you try `df.plot.area(ax=ax, lw=0)`?

Comment: I realize this is a [mre] (good job on that). For `df.plot` there's no need to create the fig and axes beforehand. Just `ax = df.plot.area(lw=0, figsize=(4, 4))`; tested in `pandas 1.3.2` and `matplotlib 3.4.3`.

Comment: Well, did you try to set the linewidth to zero? Does that stll generate an unwanted plot?

Comment: inddeed, please post this as an answer...